# How can I apply css to the child tag from component

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

`<ButtonAtom></ButtonAtom>`

this is the button components that I made.

```
<template>
 <div>
  <button class="px-2 py-1" :class="[borderRadius, backgroundColor]">
    <slot />
  </button>
 <div>
</template>
```

and this is the html tag inside the components.

If I add css to the `<ButtonAtom>` like `<ButtonAtom color="white">`

color connects to the root tag which is `<div>`

the point is if I try to connect the css to `<button>`.

Is there any ways to connect to `<button>` without deleting the root html `<div>`

P.S this is vue3.

Comment: attribute `color="white"` isn't css - if you want to have an property named `color` - use [props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props-declaration)

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a style attribute with `color:white` as property `<ButtonAtom style="color:white">` then inside the child component add `inheritAttrs:false` and bind that `$attrs` to the button element:

```html
<template>
 <div>
  <button class="px-2 py-1" v-bind="$attrs" :class="[borderRadius, backgroundColor]">
    <slot />
  </button>
 <div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a shorter example but have you already tried this:

```
<button style="color: white"></button>
```

Comment: that would hard code the color of the button inside the component - that's not what the OP wants

Comment: what they want is to pass a property that is used on the `<button>`, for some reason they think the existence of  `<div>` stops them from doing so because they think the `<div>` would get the `color` attribute. But, it's only `class` and `style` and any attributes that are not declared as props in the compoenent that behave that way - which is why I suggested they use props. Hope that clears up why your answer is not addressing any aspect of the question. OP also things `color="white"` is somehow CSS

Answer (score 0):

you can pass in the color as a prop to the button component and use it on the button itself

```
      <template>
     <div>
      <button class="px-2 py-1" v-bind="$attrs" :class="[borderRadius, backgroundColor]">
        <slot />
      </button>
     <div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
    color: String,
  }
    }
    </script>
```

and use it in the parent component like

```
<ButtonAtom color="white">
```

Comment: You should add more info about how to use the props in the child component.